# Why ./script/generate model X does not generate spec/models/X_spec.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm on Rails 2.3.2 + Rspec 1.3.2...On other projects, I noticed that when I do ./script/generate model X, it would create spec files for me instead of test unit files.  But for some reason it's not...

I have Rspec installed properly as it can be ran and what not.  I know you can do ./script/generate rspec_model X, but still, I remember being able to replace test unit outright.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: did you figure this out? Having same issue

Answer (score 1):

You need [`rspec-rails`](https://github.com/dchelimsky/rspec/wiki/rails) gem.

Comment: I have that gem installed.

gem 'rspec', '1.3.2'
gem 'rspec-rails', '1.3.4'